# Vue. Добавить класс по клику на кнопку

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Необходимо по нажатию на кнопку добавлять ей класс. Проблема в том, что по нажатию класс добавляется всем существующим кнопкам.

Как это можно исправить?

````
<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="addClass" :class="{'btn-true': isAddClass}" class="simp-btn">день дня</button>
  <button v-on:click="addClass" :class="{'btn-false': isAddClass}" class="simp-btn">день вчера</button>
  <button v-on:click="addClass" :class="{'btn-false': isAddClass}" class="simp-btn">ъ</button>
</div>```

el: '#app',
data: {
    isAddClass: false,
},
methods: {
    addClass: function () {
        this.isAddClass = true;
    },
}
````

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1332579/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be-vuejs/1332868#1332868

Comment: спасибо, помогло!

Comment: можете там + ответу поставить